Row wise average in SQL Server
I have a table in SQL Server named MyTable.
I want to calculate the row wise average of two columns (say val1 and val2). To my knowledge, I know that this can be done as shown below in my approach. But is there any other way to do it quicker and without having to specify the denominator?
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    var CHAR(1)  CHECK (var IN ('A', 'B', 'C')),
    var2 CHAR(2) CHECK (var2 IN ('AA', 'BB', 'CC')),
    val1 INT CHECK (val1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)),
    val2 INT CHECK (val2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
);


INSERT INTO MyTable (var, var2, val1, val2) 
VALUES ('A', 'AA', 1, 2),
       ('B', 'BB', 3, 4),
       ('A', 'BB', 1, 2),
       ('B', 'BB', 3, 4),
       ('A', 'BB', 1, 2),
       ('B', 'CC', 3, 4),
       ('A', 'CC', 1, 2),
       ('B', 'BB', 3, 4),
       ('C', 'CC', 5, 1);
  
SELECT
    var,
    var2,
    val1,
    val2,
    (val1 + val2) / 2 AS var3
FROM
    Mytable


Define "quicker", why do you think (val1+val2)/2 is "slow"?

Funnily, your code won't work, you need / 2.0. Otherwise, not sure how much simpler you want it

@ThomA I do not want to define the denoimator.Is there a average of columns function in sql server ?

Side note meanginful names for sample data and expected results is incredibly helpful. I'm assuming your expression aliased as var3 (which I was read as "variable 3", but it's not a variable) is your "row wise average".

"Is there a average of columns function in sql server ?" No.

You can do a subquery: select a,b,c, (select avg(v * 1.0) from (values(val1),(val2)) v(v)) from yourtable but not sure it will be shorter

Though i still don't understand why you think definitely the divisor is slow.

There are no horizontal aggregate functions. In the relational model the table is the relation between the things stored in the columns. You can't sum or average different things. Some databases may have some extension methods for very, very rare cases but in general, databases don't have row-wise aggregates

Well, we do have MAX and MIN versions now, @PanagiotisKanavos: GREATEST and LEAST.

Those are conditional operators not aggregate operators.

I'm not sure I follow, @PanagiotisKanavos, MAX(SomeExpression) GREATEST(SomeExpression,AnotherExpression,MoreExpression); in both you define the values. GREATEST is far easier than: CASE WHEN (SomeExpression > AnotherExpression OR AnotherExpression IS NULL) AND (SomeExpression > MoreExpression OR MoreExpression IS NULL) THEN SomeExpression WHEN (AnotherExpression > MoreExpression OR MoreExpression IS NULL) THEN AnotherExpression ELSE MoreExpression END;

No, in MAX the function has no idea how many individual values there are and works on the entire result set. In the conditional operator GREATEST the values are passed explicitly. Their number never changes from one invocation to another. GREATEST is a non-standard convenience function that exists in the other major databases. If the others add a row-wise AVG_VALUES, SQL Server may get one as well.

I think you missed the point, @PanagiotisKanavos .

@PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean by "non-standard"?

In order to use aggregate function row-wise you can "unpivot" table with CROSS APPLY and then calculate aggregate:
SELECT m.*, r.calc_average
FROM MyTable AS m
CROSS APPLY (SELECT AVG(s.v) 
            FROM (VALUES (m.val1),(m.val2)) AS s(v) -- here goes column list
            ) AS r(calc_average);

db<>fiddle demo

Side note: Argument type determines result type.

nice approach but how can you convert to decimal 5,2 ?

@HomerJaySimpson Explicit cast: SELECT AVG(CAST(s.v AS DECIMAL(5,2))) - https://dbfiddle.uk/hjCHmNCN
